# How to statistically test correlation and coincidence between two negative binomially distributed sets of counts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, negative-binomial-distribution, bioinformatics

I am working with novel Next Generation Sequencing (NGS) method which reports DNA breaks with perfect single nucleotide-resolution and strand-specificity.  The outcome of the technique is that the first base of the Illumina sequencing read is the 5'-terminal base at the DNA strand break site (the x coordinate of the peak), and the read count at this position is height of the peak (the y coordinate). The technique maps DNA breaks on each strand independently, so there is no intrinsic technical reason for a link between fine-scale positions or magnitudes of peaks on the top and bottom strand.

Like all NGS techniques, our raw data is composed of a mixture of *signal* (the type of DNA break we are interested in) and *noise*. I would like to filter out the *noise*.

The *signal* we are trying to map is a particular type of DNA *double-strand* break, with a specific staggered cleavage on the top and bottom strand. These breaks are not generated by a restriction enzyme, and it should be assumed that they are independent of the underlying primary DNA sequence and genome region.

Therefore, one useful characteristic of the *signal* is that it exists as cognate pairs of relatively greater magnitude sites on the top and bottom DNA strand, with a specific offset of exactly +3 bp (bottom strand vs top). The *noise* does not exhibit this feature, but is instead a background of relatively lower magnitude sites "randomly" distributed on the top and bottoms strand.  Different samples contain different fractions of *signal* and *noise*, due to technical variability in the library preparation.

Please see the linked table for an example of some of the data, which i've also plotted as a position vs count histogram. I also attach plots showing the relationship between Top and Bottom strand counts, at a +3bp offset and at an arbitrary offset of +5bp (where there is no relationship). Finally, I also attach a cross correlation plot, showing the relationship between Top and Bottom strand signal across the genome, with a peak at +3 bp as expected.

I am trying to develop a peak-calling method which leverages the coincidence of the  cognate *signal* sites, as well as their loosely-coupled magnitudes, to call these and filter out the non-cognate *noise*. Specifically, for each cognate site, I would like to test the hypothesis that it was not generated stochastically by random coincidence of top and bottom strand *noise*.  I am not an expert statistician, but I believe that the nature of this type of data should lend itself to a powerful statistical test.

A very naive approach is simply to remove all sites on each strand below a certain number of counts (or counts per million), prior to simply selecting the remaining sites which exist in a +3bp cognate. However, this test is basically only using the coincidence of the thresholded top and bottom strand sites, not any information about their relative magnitudes (which are loosely coupled).

One advantage of the cognate nature of the sites is that positions of sites on one strand can be randomised relative to the other. Alternatively, one could simply select a different offset (e.g +5), for which there are no significant cognates. I suppose either of these strategies could be used to generate a null distribution for each library, against which the real distribution could be tested, but I'm not sure exactly what test I should use. I assume that the counts-per-basepair on each individual strand follows a negative binomial distribution. Ideally I would like to calculate FDR-adjusted p-values for each site.

I am aware that this could be posted to bionformatics.stackexchange, but in essence this is fundamentally a stats question, and not one I have encountered whilst looking at bioinformatics sources. I am I would be very grateful for any insight, pointers, and/or links to further reading relevant to this specific problem.

[image: Map of example region, showing Top (red) and Bottom (blue) strand counts.]

[image: Top strand counts vs Bottom strand counts for the +3 bp offset]

[image: Top strand counts vs Bottom strand counts for an arbitrary +5 bp offset]

[image: Cross-correlation Function for Top and Bottom strand counts, showing expected peak at +3bp]

[Example data table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nbe2v3sr7vk767/data.txt?dl=0)

Comment: It's not clear to me what's being "counted" here to provide the "signal." Is is a particular nucleotide sequence that starts at the indicated location, perhaps a mapping of NGS counts to defined genomic regions, or ...? Is this somehow related to recognition sites for restriction enzymes? How are "bottom" and "top" strands distinguished? What's the hypothesis you want to test with your "peak-calling method"? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thanks for your reply. I have edited the post for clarity on the specific points you raise.